# UpsertDE error with triggered API campaigns

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a data extension (Data Extensions > Lifecycle Campaigns > API Tables > Patient_Records_DB) that is used to capture send event data for one of our triggered campaigns. The send event capture is happening through the statement below. When I use the UpsertDE fuction and clear the data extension out before sending, the triggered campaign works fine. When there is data in the data extension and I use the UpsertDE function with the same data set, the triggered campaign errors out in the queue. I added the SendLogCount function to attempt to override the error, but this also errors out when the data extension already has data populated that is a match. Any thoughts?

```
  Set @SendLog = LookupOrderedRows("Patient_Records_DB",1,"AppointmentDateTime","FamilyID",@familyid)
  Set @SendLogCount = Rowcount(@SendLog)

IF @SendLogCount > 1 THEN
UpdateDE(
"Patient_records_DB",1,
"PatientID",@ApptSubscriberKey,
"PatientID",@ApptSubscriberKey,
    "HOHid",@HOHid,
    "PatientFirstName",@PatientFirstName,
    "FamilyID",@familyid,
    "AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt,
    "AppointmentDateTime",@PatientApptTime,
    "AppointmentTypeCode",@AppointmentTypeCode,
    "RescheduleYN",@RescheduleYN,
    "EventDate",@EventDate)

ELSE

InsertDE(     
    "Patient_Records_DB",
    "PatientID",@ApptSubscriberKey,
    "HOHid",@HOHid,
    "PatientFirstName",@PatientFirstName,
    "FamilyID",@familyid,
    "AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt,
    "AppointmentDateTime",@PatientApptTime,
    "AppointmentTypeCode",@AppointmentTypeCode,
    "RescheduleYN",@RescheduleYN,
    "EventDate",@EventDate)

ENDIF

  /*UpsertDE(     
    "Patient_Records_DB",1,"PatientID",@ApptSubscriberKey,
    "PatientID",@ApptSubscriberKey,
    "HOHid",@HOHid,
    "PatientFirstName",@PatientFirstName,
    "FamilyID",@familyid,
    "AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt,
    "AppointmentDateTime",@PatientApptTime,
    "AppointmentTypeCode",@AppointmentTypeCode,
    "RescheduleYN",@RescheduleYN,
    "EventDate",@EventDate)*/
```

Comment: What is the Primary Key on `Patient_Records_DB`?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs PatientID

Comment: Is Patient_Records_DB a TriggeredSendDataExtension?  I assume it is based on your statement, "I have a data extension that is used to capture send event data for one of our triggered campaigns."  TriggeredSendDataExtension cannot have a primary key.  But, the UpsertDE() function requires that the specified data extention have a primary key.

Comment: It's not being used for the triggered send in the triggered send definition. It is only used to capture the send event data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to specify the PatientID field twice. It looks like you are setting PatientID as the match column, but then also specifying it as a column you want to insert into. You do not need to do this, setting it as the match column automatically sets it as a column that gets inserted to.

So just remove one of these from the function call: `"PatientID",@ApptSubscriberKey,`

Also, you don't need to do the LookUp and conditional logic to do update vs. insert. Upsert takes care of that for you automatically. All you need is the following code:

```
UpsertDE(     
"Patient_Records_DB",1,
"PatientID",@ApptSubscriberKey,
"HOHid",@HOHid,
"PatientFirstName",@PatientFirstName,
"FamilyID",@familyid,
"AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt,
"AppointmentDateTime",@PatientApptTime,
"AppointmentTypeCode",@AppointmentTypeCode,
"RescheduleYN",@RescheduleYN,
"EventDate",@EventDate)
```

Comment: Thanks @jonsakas. We had tried that before and for some reason it wasn't working. Likely could have been another error in the template that we were thinking was the Upsert.